# do some math/manipulate 'find' output in a windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to output a file (count.txt) with the name of each csv and tab file in the current directory and the number of lines in that file.  Although the tab file needs its value divided by 4.  Also, I would like to get rid of the 10 dashes 'find' outputs and maybe rework the filename.  How do i grab the out put of find and manipulate it?

```
    del count.txt
    for %%f in (*.csv) do (
        find /c /v "" %%f >> count.txt
    )
    for %%f in (*.tab) do (
 ::need to divide the next value by 4
        find /c /v "" %%f >> count.txt
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to correct errors and adapt to comments

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Define extensions to handle
    set "extensions=.tab .csv"

    rem Define dividers for each extension
    set ".tab=4"
    set ".csv=1"

    rem Retrieve starting folder from command line
    rem If not present, assume current folder 
    set "root=%~1" & if not defined root set "root=%cd%"

    rem For each folder starting at the indicated root 
    rem     Change current path to the folder that will be processed and
    rem       (%%X) For each extension in list
    rem         (%%a/%%b) For each matching file/lines number processed by find command
    rem            Calculate the number of lines
    rem            Echo file information
    rem     Return to previous active directory

    (for /r "%root%" /d %%F in (.) do (
        pushd "%%~fF" && (
            for %%X in (%extensions%) do if exist ".\*%%~X" (
                for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=\:" %%a in ('
                    find /c /v "" ".\*%%~X" 2^>nul
                ') do (
                    set /a "numLines=%%b / %%~xa"
                    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
                    for %%c in (!numLines!) do (
                        endlocal
                        echo [%%~fa] [%%c]
                    )
                )
            )
            popd
        )
    )) > count.txt
```

Where the task of each of the `for` loops is

`%%F` will recurse the folder hierarchy from the indicated starting point

`%%X` will iterate over the list of extensions to handle

`%%a` will execute the `find` command over all the indicated files and split each line using a backslash and a colon. The slash is included in the output of the `find` command because we use a relative reference to each file (`.\*.csv`). That way the initial dashes and space are removed. Then the colon is used to separate the file name from the line count. At the end `%%a` will hold the file name and `%%b` the line count.

Once we have the required elements, we will need delayed expansion active to access the result of the calculation. The file extensions is used to determine the divider using variables defined for each case.

`%%c` Having delayed expansion active generates a problem with files that contain an `!` it its name, so we need to disable (`endlocal`) the delayed expansion before executing the `echo`, so an aditional `for` command is used to hold the value of the number of lines that need to be echoed. With delayed expansion disabled, the information is echoed.

The outer `for` loop is enclosed in parenthesis so we can redirect all the output opening the output file only once instead of one open/write operation for each file.

Comment: There is so much good stuff in here.  Thank you.  One thing I did not mention is that the directory may not contain both file types and it seems to output nothing if there is not at least one of each files.  Simply replicating the 'for' loop for each file type with a '>> count.txt' instead of '> count.txt' did the trick.  Any chance this can easily be made to search all sub-directories?

Comment: @flysher, `find` behaviour on missing files handled by an aditional loop over the file extensions. Also, an aditional loop will handle the folder recursion. Answer updated.